# Perl cgi read from txt file

Tags: perl, cgi

this is my Apache error log:

```
[Fri Nov 15 08:55:41.771706 2013] [cgi:error] [pid 4292:tid 1500] [client ::1:35659] AH01215: [Fri Nov 15 08:55:41 2013] testaccounts.pl: Could not open accounts.txt: No such file or directory at C:/wamp/www/testaccounts.pl line 42., referer: http://localhost/testaccounts.pl
```

I am trying to read from a file that is in the same directory as my script.
I am using wamp and running the script on my local-host on my pc.

I just want my program to print every line in the file.

On the browser it says:

```
Software error:
 Could not open accounts.txt: No such file or directory at C:/wamp/www/testaccounts.pl line 42.
```

Here is the part of my program cauing the error:

```
elsif (param('username') and param('password')) #if a user-name and password is typed   in
{
 $username=(param('username'));
 $password=(param('password'));
 $title = 'Account: ' . $username;

my $file = 'accounts.txt';
open $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$file>)  {   
    print $line;
```

}

I have also tried:

```
  my $file = '/accounts.txt';
  $file = $dir . $file;
```

which gives me:

```
 Could not open C:/wamp/www/accounts.txt: No such file or directory at C:/wamp/www/testaccounts.pl line 45.
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the full path to the file. The current working directory is not the one where the script resides (see [Cwd](http://p3rl.org/Cwd) for details).

Comment: I have tried what you said and updated my answer. Could you further explain? Thanks